How do i extract assets from a binary file?

Extracting assets from Binary Files: Some Assets Corrupt
I'm working on a project where I need to extract assets (images, audio, gifs, etc.) from binary files. I wrote a script to extract PNGs, but while some images are extracted successfully, others are corrupt. Here is my code:
main.py:
import os
from src.bin2png import bin2png

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.\\Bin'):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.bin'):
            continue
        print(f'Found file: {file}')
        bin2png(os.path.join(root, file), './png')
    print('DONE')

bin2png.py:
import os
import re
import binascii

def bin2png(file_path: str, save_path: str):
    counter = 0
    png_pattern = re.compile(r'89504E47.*?49454E44AE426082', re.IGNORECASE)
    file_path = file_path.replace('\\', '/')
    file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1][:-4]
    save_path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name)

    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.mkdir(save_path)

    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        for match in png_pattern.findall(str(binascii.hexlify(file.read()))):
            with open('{}/{}.png'.format(save_path, counter), 'wb+') as image:
                image.write(binascii.unhexlify(match))
                counter += 1
    
    if counter != 0:
        print('Successfully extracted {} PNGs from file {}'.format(counter, file_name))
    else:
        print('Failed to find PNGs in file {}'.format(file_name))

Some images are extracted successfully, but others are corrupt. While inspecting the binary file, I found this hex code snippet:
A9 70 6E 67 2D 2A 3A 2A 20 20 20 2D 69 68 64 72 20 20 20 5F 20 20 CD 5F 26 75 39 D4 8C EF B0 3E 34 AC C3 23 A9 A3 4D 1D A0 FA 5D F8 32 EF 60 76 75 18 E2 88 D4 24

It looks like a PNG file header, but it's off by 0x20. I wrote this code to modify the hex string:
hex_modifier.py:
def modify_hex_string(hex_string):
    hex_values = hex_string.split()
    modified_values = []
    
    for hex_value in hex_values:
        int_value = int(hex_value, 16)
        
        modified_value = abs(0x20 - int_value)
        
        modified_value = max(0, min(modified_value, 0xFF))
        
        modified_values.append(format(modified_value, '02X'))
    
    result_string = ' '.join(modified_values)
    
    return result_string

hex_string = "A9 70 6E 67 2D 2A 3A 2A 20 20 20 2D 69 68 64 72 20 20 20 5F 20 20 CD 5F 26 75 39 D4 8C EF B0 3E 34 AC C3 23 A9 A3 4D 1D A0 FA 5D F8 32 EF 60 76 75 18 E2 88 D4 24"
result = modify_hex_string(hex_string)
print(f"Result: [{result}]")

The output was:
Result: [89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 3F 00 00 AD 3F 06 55 19 B4 6C CF 90 1E 14 8C A3 03 89 83 2D 03 80 DA 3D D8 12 CF 40 56 55 08 C2 68 B4 04]


It seems like the header is now correct, but I'm still facing issues with some assets being corrupt. Any ideas on what might be going wrong or how to fix this, and what do you recommend me a tool to use or an article to read?

Where do these files come from, and how were they created?

@OldBoy From a game. I know that the game used a custom engine made using the sdl2 library.

OK, so do you have a document that details the internal structure of the file?

No, not really. I don't have anything.


how to fix this, and what do you recommend me a tool to use

First step would be to determine true nature of yours .bin files. Many files formats have specific signature at their beginning. You might read e.g. 32 first bytes of one of files (let say it is named file.bin) and shown them in hex form following way
import binascii
with open("file.bin", "rb") as f:
    signature = f.read(32)
print(binascii.hexlify(signature, sep=" "))

then compare it with List of file signatures if there is match (note that some signatures are shorter, so you should determine if any shown signature is prefix of revealed bytes) then you known file format and might be able to find tools for dealing with said format.

Hey, thanks for the help. I already did that, I forgot to mention it. But the files for some reason don't start with any signature rather some of them start with file name e.g. "chicken" and others start with file paths e.g. "Game/Terrains/Packs" or "Game/Characters/outfits.xml"
